# Can anyone help, why google page speed said "Client site redirect" and my domain has a google selected chronical "http://ww82.gooogleapi.com"?

Tags: google-search-console

Search Console Error

[image: 1]

Google Page Speed Error

[image: 2]

My domain www.tanviralamhira.com is not indexing and also I cannot even check google page speed. problems are shown in the screenshot. Can anybody help, how can I solve it?

I have tried several time to check and index request but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue!

The problem was in the string

script src='https://ajax.gooogleapi.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.35/jquery.min.js

Remove this string or change a link to jquery library and check wether redirect disappears. Interestingly, the link looks legit and thus doesnt warn one at all, nevertheless...

Good luck!